# Why are my subprocesses running sequentially, rather than all at once?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

My script has two loops:

- in the first one multiple `ssh`-processes are launched, one for each remote machine;
- in the second I collect and print each process' stderr, stdout, and examine its `returncode`

I see, that they all run in sequence -- confirmed by printed output of the `date`-commands on each -- whereas I expected them to run in parallel... What am I doing wrong?

```py
pipes = {}
myhostname = os.uname()[1].lower()
for node in Nodes:
    if node.lower() == myhostname:
        cmd = '/bin/bash'
    else:
        cmd = ('ssh -q '
            '-o PasswordAuthentication=no '
            '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '
            '%s /bin/bash') % node
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '),
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE, close_fds = True,
        encoding = locale.getlocale()[1])
    pipe.stdin.write("""
        date
        sleep 1
        date
        exit""")
    pipes[node] = pipe

logging.info('%d processes spawn, collecting outputs', len(pipes))
errCount = 0
for (node, pipe) in pipes.items():
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    if err:
        logging.warn('%s stderr: %s', node, err.strip())
    if out:
        logging.info('%s stdout: %s', node, out.strip())
    if pipe.returncode != 0:
        errCount += 1
        logging.error('Got exit code %d from %s, increasing '
            'error-count to %d', pipe.returncode, node, errCount)
```

Comment: Isn't for loop forcing it to be sequential? It will pick one item in each iteration.

Comment: You start them in sequence, you process the output in sequence, but the processes should run in parallel. And BTW you don't seem to wait for the commands to finish before reading the output.

Comment: @KlausD `communicate()` waits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you’re writing to each process are waiting in your process’s output **buffers** until you call `communicate` on each, flushing and closing each one’s input.  You do that in sequence, so the `date` commands run in sequence, even though the `ssh` processes are all running the entire time in parallel.  With this little data, you can add `pipe.stdin.flush()` immediately after the `write` to get the desired effect.  (See Allan Wind’s answer for the general case for more (bytes of) commands.)

Comment: Duh! Of course, it is buffering. Yeah, adding an explicit `flush()` -- or just adding `bufsize = 1`  to the `Popen`'s arguments (which enables line-buffering) -- solves it.

Answer (score 2):

The data you write to the client is smaller than the write buffer so it's it's only implicitly flushed when you call `os.communicate()` in the 2nd loop.  As `os.communicate()` is blocking this will effectively serialize execution.  Calling `pipe.stdin.flush()` after `pipe.stdin.write()` will write the data to the child process.  You can also set `bufsize=1` for line buffering although this behaved differently for me than documented "1 means line buffered (only usable if text=True or universal_newlines=True)" as neither of those two were test in my test.

```
import locale
import logging
import os
import subprocess

Nodes = (
        'localhost',
        'localhost2',
)
myhostname = os.uname()[1].lower()
pipes = {}
for node in Nodes:
    cmd = '/bin/bash'
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '),
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE, close_fds = True,
        encoding = locale.getlocale()[1],
    )
    pipe.stdin.write("""
        date
        sleep 3
        date
    """)
    pipe.stdin.flush()
    pipes[node] = pipe

logging.info('%d processes spawn, collecting outputs', len(pipes))
errCount = 0
for (node, pipe) in pipes.items():
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    if err:
        logging.warn('%s stderr: %s', node, err.strip())
    if out:
        print(out.strip())
        logging.info('%s stdout: %s', node, out.strip())
    if pipe.returncode != 0:
        errCount += 1
        logging.error('Got exit code %d from %s, increasing '
            'error-count to %d', pipe.returncode, node, errCount)
```

and here is the corresponding output:

```
Fri Aug  4 02:21:28 EDT 2023
Fri Aug  4 02:21:31 EDT 2023
Fri Aug  4 02:21:28 EDT 2023
Fri Aug  4 02:21:31 EDT 2023
```

That said note the [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess):

> Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

As `communicate()` is blocking you would need to execute each of those concurrently (threads, futures, multiprocess).  For example:

```
import threading

# ...

def run(node, pipe):
    out, err = pipe.communicate(input="""
        date
        sleep 3
        date
    """)
    if err:
        logging.warn('%s stderr: %s', node, err.strip())
    if out:
        print(out.strip())
        logging.info('%s stdout: %s', node, out.strip())
    if pipe.returncode != 0:
        errCount += 1
        logging.error('Got exit code %d from %s, increasing '
            'error-count to %d', pipe.returncode, node, errCount)

logging.info('%d processes spawn, collecting outputs', len(pipes))
errCount = 0
threads = []
for (node, pipe) in pipes.items():
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[node, pipe])
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This interleaves `print()` / `logging()` from different processes.  If you care move processing of output to the last `for t in threads` loop.

Comment: The OS does buffer (at least a small amount of) pipe data, but it makes even a single byte of that immediately available to the reader.  The problematic buffering here is in the writer _rather_ than providing the data to the OS.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks.  Revised it in line with your answer.  Not that I doubt you but do you a reference?  pipe(2) says "Data written to the write end of  the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe.".  Presumably bash and ssh does the read.

Comment: There’s just more than one kind of buffering here, and there’s an observable effect of each kind and of the limits of each kind.  The man page is describing the OS buffering; it can’t delay the reader, but its limits are what drive the need for things like `communicate`/`select` (that I didn’t bother with in my answer because the example didn’t happen to hit them).  The user-space buffering (analogous to [that in C](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05)) is the reverse: hitting its limits _flushes_ data, but otherwise it is delayed indefinitely.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks, and yeah, I realize the pipe(2) quote was talking about the kernel and in support for your point.

Answer (score -1):

Have short look at the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess): *Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance.*

So `subprocess` won't start another thread, that is run in paralell. It just spawns a sub-process, waits for the results and returns. For what you want to achieve, the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading) might be more relevant.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to Popen?  If I put a print statement at the end of the first loop it executes right away.

Comment: That’s only for `subprocess.run` and friends.

Comment: The OP's code is fine other than missing the `flush` call as pointed out by Davis Herring. Once that's added, it will spawn a bunch of subprocesses and write to them in one loop; then all are allowed to run, and the second loop collects the results. There's no need to create threads in order to interact with subprocesses in parallel.